# One-line 100% width block elements positioning?

Tags: css, position

Please check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zFEcV/

I need to extend the `green` div, **with no JS included**, to the right side of the `red` one, so they both take 100% of the line. I am almost certain this can be done without JS, but don't know how.

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the *float:right;*

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zFEcV/4/)**

```
.right { /*float:right;*/ height:100px; background:green; }
```